# Issue with post a value to another page

Tags: php

My action page..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo 'OK';
}
```

another Page..

```
<form methos="post" action="action.php">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

this is not working but its working as

```
(action="#")
```

and include action in another page.

Comment: can you clarify what code is in which file?

Comment: index.php <html>
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="value">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

You have a spelling mistake:

**Replace:**

```
<form methos="post" action="action.php">
```

**With:**

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
```

that's it. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **change this `methos="post"`  to this `method="post"`**

and In `action.php` page use this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    echo $value;
}
```

and in `index.php`

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

**EDIT 01**

**Improved `action.php`**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    if (empty($value)) {
        echo "Post value is Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $value;
    }        
}
```

Comment: it cant be. its only call function when submit is clicked

Comment: may be he is getting error because of posting empty value,

Answer (score 1):

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>        
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo

```
<form methos="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

should become

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

The rest of the code should be ok.

Comment: This code working if the action page is included in index and give form action (#)

Comment: While Changing EDIT01 values in action.php no values are displayed just empty page...

Answer (score 0):

i have tried with this condition but getting only the else output

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value = $_POST['value'];
echo $value;
}else {
echo 'Not Post.';
}
```

Guys I Have find the solution there is no problem with any code, its due to (.htaccess) file after i removed the file all codes are working, i don't know why this happening but if you can please find and solve this issues...

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

#error documment..
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/error/403
```